# How to get Facebook User Test Access Token C#

Tags: c#, facebook, token

I want to make a unit test that call a function which needs User Access Token. Since the facebook User Test Access Token is only valid for 24 hours I always need to recopy User Access Token in my facebook developer page.

[image]

Comment: If it is a unit test, why can you not mock it? I am curious.

Comment: The function called by the unit test needs a valid facebook token. This function use the token to get users informations.